Safari iOS Bug with Multiselect in Forms - Popover Not Opening on Retrying Selection After Failed Submit
I'm experiencing an issue with a multiselect input in forms on iOS devices (iPad and iPhone) when using Safari. If the multiselect is left empty and the form is submitted, a validation message appears on the input field, which is expected behavior.
The issue arises when I attempt to interact with the multiselect after this validation: clicking on the input does not open the popover for selecting options, making it impossible to meet the form’s requirements. Interestingly, if I click outside of the input field or reset the form, the popover can be opened again. This issue seems isolated to Safari on iOS, as it works as expected in Chrome on the same devices.
I expected that after the failed validation, clicking on the multiselect would open the popover, allowing me to select options. I’ve tested this on iOS versions 17 and 18, but the issue might occur on other versions as well.
Here’s a link to reproduce the issue:
https://codepen.io/chernitsov/full/abejEyY (test with iPad/iPhone on Safari)
Video: https://imgur.com/a/Lj5cGKi
<form id="form-validation" class="flex flex-col gap-4 p-4 shadow-lg">
  <!-- Multi Select -->
  <label for="select-multi-field" class="font-medium">Multi Select</label>
  <select
    id="select-multi-field"
    name="select-multi-field"
    required
    multiple
    class="border border-gray-300 rounded px-3 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
  >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>

  <!-- Submit and Reset Buttons -->
  <div class="flex gap-2">
    <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-300">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>

Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this issue?
